# Best way to accomplish parallel function execution with a queue in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

**What I want to accomplish:** I have a long lit of long running GPU processes which I want to execute one per GPU until they are all finished. When one process finishes on a GPU and the GPU is freed, then the next in the list should start until there are no more left.

I have been looking through what I can find online for python's asyncio, and multiprocessing libraries and I can't figure out which one would best accomplish what I want to do.

It seems to me like making two queue's, one with available GPU's, and one with a list of processes, and then using asyncio to push GPU numbers to the queue when they are available and pop out new processes until they are finished would be the way to go. I made an initial attempt to do this with multiprocessing, but each of the processes will need to spawn child processes as well so I ended up with the error `python daemonic processes are not allowed to have children` so I am not sure if the multiprocessing module is the way to go or not.

What is the cleanest way to accomplish this in Python?